# Selecting distinct combinations

Tags: sql

I have a table which has 2 fields (`latitude`, `longitude`) and many other fields. I want to select the *distinct* combinations of latitude and longitude from this table.

What would be the query for that?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Simply use the `DISTINCT` keyword:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Latitude, Longitude 
FROM Coordinates;
```

This will return values where the `(Latitude, Longitude)` combination is unique.

This example supposes that you do not need the other columns. If you do need them, i.e. the table has `Latitude, Longitude, LocationName` columns, you could either add `LocationName` to the distinct list, or use something along the lines of:

```
SELECT Latitude, Longitude, MIN(LocationName)
FROM Coordinates
GROUP BY Latitude, Longitude;
```

Comment: For me two query returns different number of result. For example first query returns 1000 rows and second query (first query +  GROUP BY clause) returns 800 rows.

Comment: The second query get only one (more or less random) LocationName, if you have more than one.

Comment: Oh, I used to think "distinct" applies only to the column right next to it. So "select distinct" is a different statement than "select", "distinct" is not a modifier/operation on a column!

Answer (score 13):

its an old post. but I just came across it while looking for an anser for the same problem. The above answer didn't work for me, but I found another simple solution using CONCAT():

```
SELECT *
FROM Coordinates
GROUP BY CONCAT(Latitude, Longitude);
```

This will give you all the unique Latitude / Longitude combinations, without any limitations to the select part of the query.

Comment: for some reason concat doesn't work for me, it causes an error in the query and when I type the query in http://127.0.0.1:8080/phpmyadmin, having installed wamp,  it doesn't even pop up as an option http://i.imgur.com/Egqpwct.png

Comment: This is by far the most flexible solution; unfortunately, this answer relies on a partial `GROUP BY` clause.  Users who are unable to ensure that the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` MySQL mode is disabled at query time _or_ are using a managed service that doesn't allow for this mode to be changed (e.g. CloudSQL as of May '20) are unable to take advantage of this solution.

Comment: Cannot group on fields selected with '*'.

Answer (score 2):

I think it will be something about :

```
SELECT latitude, longitude 
FROM table_name t1 
INNER JOIN table_name t2 
WHERE t1.latitude <> t2.latitude OR t1.longitude <> t2.longitude
```

That is the SELF INNER JOIN.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COLUMN1,COLUMN2 
FROM TABLE_NAME 
GROUP BY COLUMN1,COLUMN2 -- This will fetch the unique combinations

-- During this kind of selection it is always better to give a where condition so that the results are filtered before grouping
```

Your Code:

```
SELECT Latitude, Longitude 
  FROM Coordinates
GROUP BY Latitude, Longitude
```

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT DISTINCT BY ( latitude, longitude)
```

This will work.